# Установка драйверов Nvidia Geforce FX5500.

Tags: nvidia, ubuntu

Как поставить на ubuntu 12.04, я новичок, можно все подробно?

Comment: Мне кажется, что лучше чем nvidia.ru, не будет. А вот там уж все подробно.

Answer (score 2):

В убунте есть менеджер драйверов. Он сам загрузит и установит проверенный драйвер в вашу систему. Если всё же хочется руками то:

1. загружаем драйвер с сайта Nvidia
2. останавливаем икс сервер - `/etc/init.d/ligthxdm stop`
3. запускаем драйвер `sh /home/имя учётки/Nvidia.run`
4. перезапускаемся и радуемся :)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно просто драйвера версии 173.14.35 и все будет ок.У меня такая же проблема была.